# cannot install Ubuntu 16 on a Compaq Presario CQ57-229WM alongside Win7 Home Premium 64-bit

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I've attempted to install Ubuntu 16 desktop alongside Win7 using both a USB drive and DVD install -- Ubuntu 16 runs great directly from the media!  However, in attempting to install alongside Win7 on this Compaq Presario (circa 2010-2011 production), it **DOES** detect the Win7 operating system but the only choices are to delete the existing OS -OR- "Other" for installs.  I have successfully installed previous versions of Ubuntu alongside Windows on other laptops and have never encountered this issue before.  I believe this laptop has an AMD C10 processor.  Can anyone please help?  Thank you!!!

Comment: Please provide step by step options you choose. Where is it you found "Other" option?

Comment: This is because of dynamic partitions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Dynamic partition. You need to convert it to basic. Either using windows disk management system or using some software e.g EaseUS partition master. But before you do it, make sure that you backed up all of your important data.